# Hibernate Oracle 12c unable to determine dialect

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I am trying to connect to Oracle 12c using hibernate version 3.6.10.Final.
When i do 
org.hibernate.cfg.configuration.buildSessionFactory()

I get

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect to use [name=Oracle, majorVersion=12]; user must register resolver or explicitly set 'hibernate.dialect'.

When i am using Oracle 11g i don't have this problem the dialect is autodetected to org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect.
Why for Oracle 12c it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe because your outdated version of Hibernate predates Oracle 12c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate in your version cannot guess what dialect to use with Oracle12c.
However, you may force to use Oracle10 dialect.

Here is a spring configuration and the `databasePlatform` property which does the job.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <!-- this property forces Oracle10 on Oracle12c since Hibernete cannot guess it! -->
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
  </bean>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue even appears for Oracle19c. So its better to upgrade the hibernate to Hibernate 5.4 and above and then use the following property in persistence.xml:

```html
<property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect"/>
```

Note that the Dialect used is for Oracle12c, but it also works for Oracle19c. This must be explicitly provided when Hibernate is not able to recognize the Dialect on its own

Answer (score -2):

Hibernate 3.6.10 doesn't support Oracle 12. StandardDialectResolver can't resolve the dialect for Oracle12

Comment: I am running Hibernate 3.6.10 with Oracle 12c, so the problem is not Hibernate's version. Usually, the problem is that, unlike Oracle 11g, Oracle 12c needs the dialect you want to use to be explicitly stated.